# Factory-like method as abstract template method

Tags: java, generics

Say I have an abstract base class that has a method to generate `Foo` objects (acting like a factory method). Right now my classes look something like this:

```
public class Foo
{
}

public class FooBar extends Foo
{
}

public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    abstract public Foo createObject();
}

public class MyDerivedClass extends MyBaseClass
{
    @Override
    public Foo createObject()
    {
        return new FooBar();
    }
}
```

This is sub-optimal, because code calling `MyBaseClass#createObject` needs to cast the return value back to what it was originally, i.e.:

```
FooBar fooBar = (FooBar)myDerivedClass.createObject();
```

This is like taking my pants off to put them on again.

I haven't used Java generics for a while, but I was hoping I could turn that abstract method into a templated method, something like:

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass
{
    abstract public <T extends Foo> T createObject();
}
```

But I get the following errors from Eclipse when I try to implement the method in the derived class:

```
public class MyDerivedClass extends MyBaseClass
{
    @Override
    public <FooBar extends Foo> FooBar createObject() // The type parameter FooBar is hiding the type FooBar
    {
        return new FooBar(); // Cannot instantiate the type FooBar
    }
}
```

I don't think I'm applying the right solution to my problem of reducing the unnecessary casting going on. Any ideas?

This is with Java 1.6.

Comment: You probably need to understand the effects of erasures on Java generics. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html

Comment: related: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10127502/697449

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for a generic class (as opposed to a generic method):

```
public abstract class MyBaseClass<T extends Foo> {
    public abstract T createObject();
}

public class MyDerivcedClass extends MyBaseClass<FooBar> {
    public FooBar createObject() {
        return new FooBar();
    }
}
```

To learn more about Java generics, I highly suggest you read the [Generics tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/index.html).